# Find $f(3)$ if $f(f(x) - y) = f(x) + f(f(y) - f(-x)) + x$

Tags: functions, real-numbers, functional-equations

Let $f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be a function such that
$$f(f(x) - y) = f(x) + f(f(y) - f(-x)) + x$$for all real numbers $x$ and $y.$

Let $n$ be the number of possible values of $f(3),$ and let $s$ be the sum of all possible values of $f(3).$ Find $n \times s.$

---

I tried plugging in some different values of $x$ and $y$ into the functional equation, but they didn't get me anywhere. I'm not really sure what to do, and any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: Hint: certain pairs $(x, y)$ yield information that can lead to identifying $f(x)$, e.g. begin by simplifying the case $(x, y) = (0, 0)$. Then, maybe $(x, y) = (0, y)$, leaving $y$ arbitrary.

Comment: Edit your post to include the work you do, and be explicit as you can about where you're stuck/confused.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [$f(f(x)−y) = f(x)+f(f(y)−f(−x))+x$ find all functions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2393122/ffx%e2%88%92y-fxffy%e2%88%92f%e2%88%92xx-find-all-functions). Found using [Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24f(f(x)%20-%20y)%20%3D%20f(x)%20%2B%20f(f(y)%20-%20f(-x))%20%2B%20x%24&p=1). Also, FYI, there's the AoPS thread [Function equation](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h1747481p11380585).